# How to contruct 'new' in assciated controller in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models in rails 3.1 app: lease_booking and lease_log. Lease_booking has_many lease_logs and lease_log belongs_to lease_booking. In routes.rb the association is:

```
resources :lease_bookings do
  resources :lease_logs
end
```

In lease_booking show.html.erb, the path to create a new lease log is:

```
<%= link_to "new Log", new_lease_booking_lease_log_path(@lease_booking) %>
```

The 'new' code in lease_log controller is:

```
  def new
    @lease_log = LeaseBooking.find(params[:id]).lease_log.new()
  end
```

However there is an error for lease_log controller 'new' after clicking 'new log':

```
Couldn't find LeaseBooking without an ID
```

It seems that the id (should be 1) of lease booking was not properly recognized in lease log controller.

The lease booking id (1) on the same error page is correct:

```
Parameters:

{"lease_booking_id"=>"1"}
```

Is there a way to fix it? Thanks.

UPDATE: Here is the output of rake routes

```
    lease_booking_lease_logs GET    /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
                             POST   /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
 new_lease_booking_lease_log GET    /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
edit_lease_booking_lease_log GET    /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
     lease_booking_lease_log GET    /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
                             PUT    /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
                             DELETE /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"lease_logs"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter output shows shat param you should be looking for - lease_booking_id :

```
@lease_log = LeaseBooking.find(params[:lease_booking_id]).lease_log.new()
```

From the console, run `rake routes` to see how the nested routes use the parameters.

Edit:

When you nest your routes the inner resources depend on the outer resource:

```
resources :lease_bookings do
  resources :lease_logs
end
```

Look at the `rake routes` output for creating your lease_log:

```
POST   /lease_bookings/:lease_booking_id/lease_logs
```

So when you set up your form you need to specify the lease_booking as well as the new lease_log (and any _path or _url methods will need to be adapted accordingly):

```
<%= simple_form_for [@lease_booking, @lease_log] do |f| %>
```

This would also require you to set the @lease_booking in your controller:

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more information on Rails routing.

```
def new
  @lease_booking = LeaseBooking.find(params[:lease_booking_id])
  @lease_log = @lease_booking.lease_log.new
end
```

Comment: A new error appears from the _form_new.html.erb: undefined method `lease_logs_path' for #<#<Class:0x5185020>:0x5180718>. There is no lease_logs_path in rake routes because of the association. The first line of the erb is: <%= simple_form_for @lease_log do |f| %>.

Comment: see link below for a complete example for constructing both controller and view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect example I found to construct both controller and view for 1-to-many association:

http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-model-1-many-association